# Indeterminacy of $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} = \frac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-0}}{0} = \frac{0}{0}.$

Tags: limits

Here we have an indeterminacy:

$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} = \dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-0}}{0} =  \dfrac{0}{0}.$

So we can use L'Hopital's rule differentiating each function: $\dfrac{d}{dh} \left(e^{-x} - e^{-x-h}\right) = \dfrac{d}{dh} (e^{-x}) - \dfrac{d}{dh} (e^{-x-h}) = 0 + e^{-x-h} = e^{-x-h}.$

Is it possible to get the same result without using differentiation?
If possible, could you demonstrate?

Comment: There is a typo, you lost a minus sign, it should be $0-e^{-x-h} = -e^{-x-h}$.

Comment: What definition do you know for $\lim_{h\to0}$ (i.e. what is your background?) Does something with $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ ring a bell or have you never heard of such a definition?

Comment: You can use the taylor series (expansion) of $e^{-x}.$

Comment: this definition I never heard

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following : Given $f$ a differentiable function, by definition $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f^\prime(x)$$
Now take $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Then the above becomes $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-x-h}-e^{-x}}{h}=(e^{-x})^\prime=-e^{-x}$$ Then multiplying everything with $-1$, we get
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x-h}}{h}=e^{-x}$$ which is the limit desired.